# Поиск необходимой IDE

Tags: ide

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, где скачать `DevRocket` (желательно последней версии)? Это среда разработки под железо на котором стоит `Linux MontaVista`. Если кто-то сталкивался, прошу помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта? 
[DevRocket Eclipse-based IDE for Platform and Application Developers](http://www.mvista.com/product_detail_devrocket.php)